# Static responsive web page builder, that can export a single html file

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

We work with lot of landing pages, and are looking for app that could speed up this process.

We have found a ton of apps that can help us, sort of. Our best entry for now is [Bootstrap Studio](https://bootstrapstudio.io). Boostrap Studio is good, as we can use it for design stage already, and skip using Sketch or Photoshop. So that already speeds us up a bit.

But catch is, since we work with different CMSs and different clients (some which won't let us publish pages for them, instead wanting to do it by themselves) with different skill levels, we need one that can export complete website into single HTML file (we already have images stored on server, so we don't need to relink them afterwards). Bootstrap Studio can export HTML, but it must include additional CSS and JS files (although bootstrap-required files can be linked from CDN).

So, my question is: Is there any platform similar to Bootstrap Studio that can export a single static responsive HTML page, without additional CSS and JS files?

Comment: Im not sure about a different tool but you could always put the CSS/JS into the individual html docs. I know its not the solution you are looking for but if the clients aren't giving you access to the document root, it might solve your problem

Comment: That's an option, but we'd like to know if there's is another tool that could do this out of box.